# ImportError: cannot import name 'Update' from 'telegram'

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

from telegram import Update
ImportError: cannot import name 'Update' from 'telegram'

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from telegram import Update


TOKEN = 'YOUR_TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN'


def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Welcome to the product search bot! Please enter a product name to search for.")


def search_product(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    product_name = update.message.text
    url = f'https://example.com/search?q={product_name}'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    products = soup.find_all('div', class_='product')

    for product in products:
        name = product.find('h3', class_='product-name').text.strip()
        price = product.find('div', class_='product-price').text.strip()
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=f'{name}\n{price}')


def main():
    updater = Updater(TOKEN)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, search_product))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I try pip uninstall python-telegram-bot
pip install python-telegram-bot --upgrade --force-reinstall
from telegram import Update
but it didnt help

Comment: Can you please provide the full error log? Look carefully at your imports: it seems that you didn't import `CallbackContext`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Django_Project\pythonProject\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from telegram import Update
ImportError: cannot import name 'Update' from 'telegram' (D:\Django_Project\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\telegram\__init__.py)

Comment: *Which* `telegram` module did you install?  There are several packages with similar names listed on PyPI - and the one you get by using the obvious `pip install telegram` is one that was abandoned over 8 years ago.

Comment: @jasonharper And how to install the version that I need?

Comment: Since you have labeled your question with `python-telegram-bot`, and because of your third import, I think you want to check this: https://python-telegram-bot.org/ . In the second section "Easy to install" you have what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install python-telegram-bot
```

just run it without other flags, it'll work